# Javascript email and phone validation regex

Tags: regex

I'd like to get a review on 2 regexes, one for email and one for phone validation.

```
/* Add jQuery validator method to check if phone numbers are in correct format.
   Use regex101.com for explaination of the regex.
   Using value.replace with / /g to remove all spaces. Normal replace with ' ' only works once. */
$.validator.addMethod('phone_number', function(value, element) {
    return /^\+(?:\d{1,3}|\d-\d{3}|\d{2}-\d{4})(?:\s?)\d{5,14}$/.test(value.replace(/ /g, ''));
});

/* Add jQuery validator method to check emails correctly.
   The original jQuery validator email method didn't correctly check double dots
   Eg. test..something@email.com worked while it's an invalid email.
 */
$.validator.methods.email = function(value, element) {
    return /^(?:(?:\w)+[._]?(?!\.))*\w@(?:(?:[a-z])+(-|\.)?(?!\.))*[a-z]\.[a-z]{2,}$/gi.test(value.replace(/\\/g,'').trim());
};
```

Regexes only:

Phone: `/^\+(?:\d{1,3}|\d-\d{3}|\d{2}-\d{4})(?:\s?)\d{5,14}$/`

Email: `/^(?:(?:\w)+[._]?(?!\.))*\w@(?:(?:[a-z])+(-|\.)?(?!\.))*[a-z]\.[a-z]{2,}$/gi`

Comment: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ + https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643 + https://mdswanson.com/blog/2013/10/14/how-not-to-validate-email-addresses.html

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. But I'd like to have some client-side email format validation as well. Also, I know lots of formats are possible. But it's a webshop and not even a webshop for every regular customer. And the usual customer doesn't have weird random characters in their email. So it's not a lot of checks I really have to do.